# Generic error 1084 after changing flex sdk from 4.6 to 3.5

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm using flex builder 4.0 with sdk 4.6. But just discovered that my earned projects, was build on 3.5 sdk. So, I downloaded the flex sdk 3.5 and added the libraries reference in the flex builder. Then after eclipse *clean & build* it display a generic error 1084 (a thousand times).

> 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program.

without *path*, I can't double click it.

Comment: Did you manually add Flex SDK SWCs to the library path of your project?  Or are you using the Flash Builder "mutli-SDK Feature"? to switch the SDK of your project?

Comment: Windows > Preferences > Flash Builder >  Installed Flex SDKs. And changed it on Project > Properties > Flex Compiler. Is it wrong ?

Comment: That is the correct approach for changing the SDK.  You may try cleaning the workspace instead of just the projects.  You can do that by launching Flash Builder w/ the -data argument to specify your workspace and the -clean argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem adding the sdk 3.5 library of swc into the project, using *Add SWC Folder* on *Flex Build Path* inside Flash Builder. Also, setting *Framework linkage* to *Merged into code*. Now its working with both sdk's like a piece of cake.